# How to disable the "This program has changed, allow it network access?" prompt

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

I have a program set up to run via Windows Task Scheduler, but if the program is re-compiled then the execution of the program is tied up with the "This program has changed, allow it access to the network?" prompt (not verbatim).  Is there a way to disable this or allow an exception for my program?

Also, please leave a comment on what that Windows feature is called.  I don't quite know how to google for solutions to it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of Windows you are running, but the message reads like one that comes from a firewall program which is monitoring outgoing connections.

You need to find the options page for your firewall and see if there's an "always allow" option where you can specify an application.

Either that or run the program interactively the first time you recompile it.

Comment: Thanks - I thought it was a new feature in Vista but I found a "Network Threat Protection" thing in my Symantec Endpoint Protection software so I'll try disabling that and see if it works.  Running it interactively is not really an option.

Comment: @weiji - I'd be reluctant to disable it completely. It helps guard against malicious software being installed and "phoning home".

Comment: Oh, I understand - but in my situation, it's okay as this is a work system, they have a lot of network-level devices and services to protect us.  Thanks for the concern!

Comment: That is indeed a prompt from Symantec Endpoint Protection.  I think if you go into the firewall rules configuration under Network Threat Protection and add your executable as an exception it should allow it without prompting whenever it changes.  As long as you don't change the name anyway.